# AngularJS theme color picker issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-components

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJbagW

In the above codepen , i have the theme color picker and it changes the color based on the button clicked.

Issue: i was wondering if it could be changed into this scenario , you pass the color you wan through directive as a parameter

For example:

```
<my-application color="blue"></my-application>
```

So in this case, the **word blue** would be taken in the directive and then the blue theme would be applied to the application. I wonder if this is possible?

I need this as I want to change the color of my directive I just created based on user's needs.

Question: Is my question above workable ? Or is there another way i could change the color of the angular theme through passing in parameters only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you can see that the directive "themePreview" already takes parameters:

```
<theme-preview primary="primary" accent="accent"></theme-preview>
```

It takes the primary and accent color passed in the attributes, you can copy that behavior in your application.

## Example:

In the codepen, change the attributes color:

```
<theme-preview primary="'purple'" accent="'yellow'"></theme-preview>
```

Since the example directive is using two-way binding, you have to single quote strings.

Or you can change to text binding `@`:

#### Directive

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'themePreview.tmpl.html',
  scope: {
  primary: '@',   //<--- Text binding
  accent:  '@'    //<--- Text binding
  }
}
```

#### Html

```
<theme-preview primary="purple" accent="yellow"></theme-preview>
```

You can look for information on **Isolate Scope** and **Local Scope Properties** to have a clear understanding of what you want to achieve. Try reading this [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope).

Comment: Hi. can i ask whether with md-color , can i apply it to buttons and other element ?? since now its only for background

Comment: Just set background like `md-colors="{background: 'purple'}"`

Comment: i am using a form in a dialog, so i want to change the color of the whole form e.g : the button color , text color.  In this case , how can i do so according to the example to top? as i think it only works with background @lbarros

Comment: I am not sure about that, I think you may have to change the elements color individually.

Comment: any tips on how to start ??